# How to create regular expression for domain name?

Tags: python, regex

I need to look if the string has less than 256 characters, and has at least one "." (dot) in it, that's all.

Please help me..

Comment: You probably want to check much more than just the length of the string and the dots in it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you asked is

```
len(s) < 256 and '.' in s
```